# surjective unique uniform distributed random choice generator

Tags: python, random, generator, distribution

How can I implement a generator function to generate some values from a domain which should be uniformly random distributed over the range of output data.

I want the randomly chosen values be unique and never be chosen again

for example, if my range is:

```
A, B, C, D, E, F, H, I
```

I want get `E` in some iteration and for example `B` in next one and never get these two again.

The data is not pre-populated in memory, so `pop()` is not a solution; and the data can be very large in volume so pre-generating and shuffling data is not a solution too.
So I want to use a generator function to generate them.

I thought about `LFSR` bijection mapping function, but is there a better solution for this?

Comment: Is your data stored in a list, like [A, B, C, D, E, F, H, I], and you want to pass it to a generator function which will yield the elements at random order?

Comment: @Andyk no! As i mentioned my datacan be very large in scale of range and i want to generate them using a generator instead of storing in memory

Comment: @RYN How large can the data be? If it is "only" a few million, you still could make a shuffled list of the indexes and pop from that list of indexes (and then retrieve that data element from disk or whereever).

Comment: You could build a custom LFSR or [LCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) with coefficients chosen to give full cycle.  In either case make the cycle length as close to the cardinality of your set as possible, and just reject the values larger than that cardinality.

Comment: Could you tell more about cardinality of the problem?